# something wrong to the edge of my custom view when calling canvas.drawArc()

Tags: android, view

I suppose to draw a circle view,and I set my paint like this:

```
    mPaintForeground.setColor(mColorForeground);
    mPaintForeground.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintForeground.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaintForeground.setStrokeWidth(20);
    mPaintForeground.setAntiAlias(true);
```

and draw it:

```
   mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) mRect.width(), (int) mRect.height(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
   if (!loadingFinished) {
       canvas.drawArc(mRect, -90, mProgress, false, mPaintForeground);
   }
```

But I found some the edge of view has been cut.
[image: edge of arc]
So how can I control the radius length in the arc?Is the problem in mRect?

Comment: start with mPaintForeground.setStrokeWidth(0); and then try increasing the stroke's width: 1, 2, 5, 10, 20 etc

Comment: @pskink I tried still problem whatever how stroke width,it seems problem happened to view's margin

Comment: reduce seekbar width n try..

Comment: ok, seems you didn't catch it: when you call canvas.drawArc the middle of your stroke will be in your mRect boundaries: some part will be inside and some part will be **outside** your Rect